# Bootstrap columns grid clarification

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As I know, grid columns are created by specifying the number of available columns you wish to span. What should I do with the empty space when I create columns and see that the sum is less than 12?

http://www.bootply.com/dmPaHyDcUg

```
 <div class="container well">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
      <label>Card<br> number</label>
      </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input data-length="4" class="txtinput" placeholder="XXXX" maxlength="4" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input data-length="4" class="txtinput" placeholder="XXXX" maxlength="4" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input data-length="4" class="txtinput" placeholder="XXXX" maxlength="4" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input data-length="4" class="txtinput" placeholder="XXXX" maxlength="4" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your question is not clear..

Comment: I guess she is not happy that container way larger than elements itself. For example card number

Comment: Ordinarily you'd expand your columns to total 12. You can also use offsets to shift the small columns toward center, or you can use nested rows to center the layout. Please update your question to clarify your goal or it's likely to be closed.

Comment: Wild Goat, yes, you are right, and I want to make this columns for a width of row, but the col-md-5 is too small and the columns don't go to the end of the row.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want. Stretching columns containing 4-character inputs would look strange. I'd probably nest all this in a `col-xs-12 col-md-6` and put some other content next to it at medium and up sizes.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this? http://www.bootply.com/FZNJ8LvyU5

Comment: isherwood, thanks I will try with nested rows. :)

Comment: makshh, thanks for your help and bootply example- it's also useful idea.

Answer (score 2):

You use an offset to compensate !

Let's say you want a 4 col wide div centered ( but rows are 12 , right ? ) you could do this :

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"></div>
```

It would look like this :

**| off 4 | 4 col | -- -- |**

now you have a 4 col wide div in the middle ( you offset it 4 cols to the right + the missing 4 cols)

Or let's say you want a 7 col wide div aligned to the right :

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
```

It would look like this :

**| off 5 | __7 c o l__ |**

As explained here : [Bootstrap Column Offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

> Move columns to the right using .col-md-offset-* classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns. For example, .col-md-offset-4 moves .col-md-4 over four columns.

Comment: You could nest a layout inside another. Does it specifically has to be 5 ? You could do a 6-6 and inside one of them you could use an 11 wide col. Or a 4-4-4 layout.. options are endless !

Comment: @DariaYemelianova please take a moment and read this ( since I see you are new here in the community ) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers